# Renedered more hooks than during the previous render only happening in one component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

In my react native component called `Turnos`, I'm trying to get an item from the async storage with a `useEffect()` hook:

```
export default function Turnos({ navigation }: any) {
  const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useQuery(GET_TURNS, {
    onError: () =>
      Alert.alert(
        "Error",
        "Hubo un error al conectarse. Por favor, verificá tu conexión a internet"
      ),
    pollInterval: 3000,
    fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
  });

  if (loading) {
    return <Loader />;
  }
  if (error) {
    Alert.alert(
      "Error",
      "Hubo un error al conectarse. Por favor, verificá tu conexión a internet"
    );
    return null;
  }

  const myTurns = data.getTurnsForUser.filter(
    (e: any) => e.fullfilled === false
  );

  const getUserId = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.getItem("USER_ID").then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserId();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        contentContainerStyle={styles.turnList}
        style={styles.turnList}
        data={myTurns}
        renderItem={(turn) => (
          <Turno
            title={turn.item.store.name}
            peopleQueue={turn.item.store.turns.length} // how many people are in the queue
          ></Turno>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(turn) => turn.id}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={false}
            onRefresh={() => {
              try {
                refetch();
              } catch (error) {
                Alert.alert("Error", String(error));
              }
            }}
          ></RefreshControl>
        }
        ListEmptyComponent={
          <View style={styles.listEmptyContainer}>
            <PrimaryText>No hay turnos por ahora...</PrimaryText>
          </View>
        }
      ></FlatList>
    </View>
  );
}
```

However, I keep getting the error: `Renedered more hooks than during the previous render`
. This is really strange, since I'm using the exact same code in another component and it works just fine:

```
const loadActiveTurn = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.getItem("HAS_ACTIVE_TURN").then((check) => {
      check === "1" ? setHasActiveTurns(true) : setHasActiveTurns(false);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadActiveTurn();
  }, []);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You question is missing the error.

Comment: It was in the title, I just edited and made it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized what the error was: Never call the `useEffect()` hook inside or after a conditional statement, as I was doing afer:

```
if (loading) {
    return <Loader />;
  }
  if (error) {
    Alert.alert(
      "Error",
      "Hubo un error al conectarse. Por favor, verificá tu conexión a internet"
    );
    return null;
  }
```

Just putting it at the top fixed it.

Comment: If you have answered your own question, can you please close it?

Comment: I wanted to leave it here in case someone had the same problem as me

Comment: since there wasn't any solution in this platform